# Is there an InnerText equivalent in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

With the code below:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), fromEncoding="utf-8")
result = soup.find('div', {'class' :'flagPageTitle'})
```

I get the following html:

```html
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Item65404" class="flagPageTitle" style=" ">
<span></span><p>Some text here</p>
</div>
```

How can I get `Some text here` without any tags? Is there InnerText equivalent in `BeautifulSoup`?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

All you need is:

```
result = soup.find('div', {'class' :'flagPageTitle'}).text
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `findAll(text=True)` to only find text nodes.

```
result = u''.join(result.findAll(text=True))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can search for `<p>` and get its text:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(page.read(), fromEncoding="utf-8")
result = soup.find('div', {'class': 'flagPageTitle'})
result = result.find('p').text
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I was looking for the way to do it without additional `find`. In your scenario I can also use `result.find('p').contents[0]`.