# how to display text only using find_all in beautiful soup?

Tags: python, text, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, findall

there is a very succinct solution to displaying text from a div using beautiful soup and `find` here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8994150/1063287 :

`result = soup.find('div', {'class' :'flagPageTitle'}).text`

i am wanting to apply the same logic in the scenario where:

`content = original_content("div","class1 class2")`

if i modify this to be:

`content = original_content("div","class1 class2").text`

i am getting the error:

`AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'text'`

can anyone please tell me how i can use the same logic initially shown but in the scenario where i am using find_all as above?  (note i am using the shortcut of `find_all` which is not to type it, see [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all))

thank you.

Comment: `find_all` returns a list: try printing `original_content("div","class1 class2", limit=1)` and see what appears.

Comment: i think that is what i have above, it was my understanding that the `find_all` is implied when leaving it out?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the implied `.find_all()` method when you call the element directly, which returns a result set (a list-like object). Using `limit` does not change what is returned, only how many are returned.

If you want to get the *first* element of that set, use slicing:

```
original_content("div","class1 class2", limit=1)[0].text
```

or be explicit about it and use `.find()` instead:

```
original_content.find("div","class1 class2").text
```

To get the text of all matches you'll need to loop over the result set. A list comprehension would be easiest:

```
[el.text for el in original_content("div","class1 class2")]
```

Comment: sorry, thank you for your reply, i can see how `limit=1` made you think i just wanted one result (it was left over from testing, sorry, i have removed it from the code above), what i want to do is use `find_all` to find all instances of the 'match' and apply the 'text' feature to all of them.  using your example, i tried `original_content("div","class1 class2")[0:-1].text` (hoping to apply it to all values in the list) but i got the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'`.

Comment: You'd still need to loop over all elements then; I'll update the answer.

Comment: wow, that is incredible, i barely understand it, cool!  i am finding though that when printing (eg `print content`, where `content` is the object name that the above list comprehension has been assigned to), the output has `u"` before the first value, `u'` before the rest of the values, and, except for the first value, each value ends with '</div>' and other tags outside of the specified div.  so it seems not to be cleanly getting the text from the specified divs.

Comment: You have a list of Unicode strings; BeautifulSoup is fully Unicode aware. You want `.string` to get *just* the direct text content; `.text` turns *everything* including the tags into text.

Comment: `content = [el.string for el in original_content("div","class1 class2")]` , `print content`, displays `[None, None, None, None, None, None]` - sorry this is turning out to be such a lengthy process.

Comment: You may want to review the documentation; there are more options here. `.strings` for example gives you a generator for all contained text. `''.join(el.strings)` gives you one aggregate string.

Comment: But you may want to ask a *new* question with example input and expected output together with your attempts so far. This question has run its course.