# extracting text from a href in a website using python and beautlfulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from a website and I need the text titles.

```
[<a href="http://www.thegolfcourses.net/golfcourses/TX/38468.htm" rel="bookmark">Feather Bay  Golf  Course and Resort</a>]
[<a href="http://www.thegolfcourses.net/golfcourses/AZ/174830.htm" rel="bookmark">Paradise Valley Country Club</a>]
[<a href="http://www.thegolfcourses.net/golfcourses/IL/129935.htm" rel="bookmark">The Golf Club at Waters Edge</a>]
[<a href="http://www.thegolfcourses.net/golfcourses/NY/10630.htm" rel="bookmark">1000 Acres Ranch Resort</a>]
[<a href="http://www.thegolfcourses.net/golfcourses/VA/995731.htm" rel="bookmark">1757 Golf Club, 1757 Golf Club Front 9 Golf Course</a>]
[<a href="http://www.thegolfcourses.net/golfcourses/WI/320815.htm" rel="bookmark">27 Pines Golf Course</a>]
[<a href="http://www.thegolfcourses.net/golfcourses/WY/823145.htm" rel="bookmark">3 Creek Ranch Golf Club</a>]
[<a href="http://www.thegolfcourses.net/golfcourses/CA/18431.htm" rel="bookmark">3 Par At Four Points</a>]
[<a href="http://www.thegolfcourses.net/golfcourses/AZ/470720.htm" rel="bookmark">3 Parks Fairways</a>]
[<a href="http://www.thegolfcourses.net/golfcourses/IA/074920.htm" rel="bookmark">3-30 Golf &amp; Country Club</a>]
```

I use this code to process it but I am having a hard time writign the code to extract this any good ideas on how to go about it?

```
import csv
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

courses_list = []

for i in range(1):
 url="http://www.thegolfcourses.net/page/{}?ls&location=California&orderby=title&radius=6750#038;location=California&orderby=title&radius=6750".format(i)
 r = requests.get(url)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)


g_data2=soup.find_all("article")


for item in g_data2:
  try:
    name= item.contents[5].find_all("a")
    print name
  except:
        name=''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `string` property

```
name= item.contents[5].find_all("a")[0].string
```

Remember that `findall` returns a list (ResultSet object), so if you know there will be only one, you can just look for the 0th index in that list.

Or you can use `find` instead, if you know there is only one result you're interested in.

```
name= item.contents[5].find("a").string
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this may work. 
[Is there InnerText equivalent in BeautifulSoup / python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993854/is-there-innertext-equivalent-in-beautifulsoup-python)

Basically try the ".text" method

```
name = item.contents[5].find_all("a").text
```

edit: sorry I can't format properly try this it's bad but it works

```
x = "<a> text </a>"
y = x.split(">")[1]
z = y.split("<")[0]
print z
 text
```

Comment: I tried that but I am still getting blanks when I excute that code.

Comment: @Gonzalo68 this is an inefficient way but it would probably work. >>> x = "<a> text </>"
>>> y = x.split(">")[1]
>>> z = y.split("<")[0]