# BeautifulSoup renderContents not returning what I expect

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape restaurant names from https://www.opentable.sg/singapore-restaurants

```
url = "https://www.opentable.sg/singapore-restaurants"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser', from_encoding="utf-8")


for entry in soup.find_all('a',{'class':'rest-row-name'}):
    #print entry.renderContents()
    print entry
```

Output:

```
<a class="rest-row-name" href="/r/chilis-clarke-quay-central-singapore">Chili's Clarke Quay Central</a>

<a class="rest-row-name" href="/r/atlas-singapore">ATLAS</a>
<a class="rest-row-name" href="/r/edge-pan-pacific-singapore-marina-
square">Edge - Pan Pacific Singapore</a>
<a class="rest-row-name" href="/r/lawrys-the-prime-rib-
singapore">Lawry's The Prime Rib Singapore</a>
<a class="rest-row-name" href="//www.opentable.sg/r/carousel-royal-
plaza-on-scotts" target="_blank"><span class="rest-row-index">1. 
</span>Carousel</a>
<a class="rest-row-name" href="//www.opentable.sg/r/bread-street-
kitchen-marina-bay-sands-singapore" target="_blank"><span class="rest-
row-index">2. </span>Bread Street Kitchen - Marina Bay Sands</a>
<a class="rest-row-name" href="//www.opentable.sg/r/colony-the-ritz-
carlton-millenia-singapore" target="_blank"><span class="rest-row-
index">3. </span>Colony - The Ritz-Carlton Millenia Singapore</a>
<a class="rest-row-name" href="//www.opentable.sg/r/edge-pan-pacific-
singapore-marina-square" target="_blank"><span class="rest-row-
index">4. </span>Edge - Pan Pacific Singapore</a>
<a class="rest-row-name" href="//www.opentable.sg/r/the-dempsey-
cookhouse-and-bar-singapore" target="_blank"><span class="rest-row-
index">5. </span>The Dempsey Cookhouse and Bar</a>
<a class="rest-row-name" href="//www.opentable.sg/r/the-westin-
singapore-cook-and-brew-singapore" target="_blank">Cook &amp; Brew - 
The Westin Singapore</a>
<a class="rest-row-name" href="//www.opentable.sg/r/pince-and-pints-
katong-singapore" target="_blank">Pince &amp; Pints Katong 
Singapore</a>
<a class="rest-row-name" href="//www.opentable.sg/r/seasonal-tastes-
the-westin-singapore" target="_blank">Seasonal Tastes  - The Westin 
Singapore</a>
<a class="rest-row-name" href="//www.opentable.sg/r/sky22-" 
target="_blank">Sky22</a>
<a class="rest-row-name" href="//www.opentable.sg/r/the-chop-house-
katong-singapore" target="_blank">The Chop House Katong</a>
```

When I want to use .renderContents() on my soup object, this is what is returned:

```
for entry in soup.find_all('a',{'class':'rest-row-name'}):
    print entry.renderContents()
```

Output:

```
Chili's Clarke Quay Central
ATLAS
Edge - Pan Pacific Singapore
Lawry's The Prime Rib Singapore
<span class="rest-row-index">1. </span>Carousel
<span class="rest-row-index">2. </span>Bread Street Kitchen - Marina 
Bay Sands
<span class="rest-row-index">3. </span>Colony - The Ritz-Carlton 
Millenia Singapore
<span class="rest-row-index">4. </span>Edge - Pan Pacific Singapore
<span class="rest-row-index">5. </span>The Dempsey Cookhouse and Bar
Cook &amp; Brew - The Westin Singapore
Pince &amp; Pints Katong Singapore
Seasonal Tastes  - The Westin Singapore
Sky22
The Chop House Katong
```

I expected only the names of restaurants to be returned when using .renderContents(). But because some of the restaurants are in a different class tag, there are some entries with html remaining, and I failed to extract the restaurant names.

What are the best practices for handling a situation like this? What should I do differently?

Comment: Have you tried `.text`? Referring from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8994150/4428377).

Comment: `
for entry in soup.find_all('a',{'class':'rest-row-name'}):
    print entry.text` seems to work pretty well!

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments, here is an approach to solution using `.text`.

```
for entry in soup.find_all('a',{'class':'rest-row-name'}): 
    print entry.text
```

Referrence taken from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8994150/4428377).