# Python 3 BeautifulSoup Strip Specific Values from a Span Class?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I've tested a few different answers that I found on here, but can't seem to get my problem sorted. Hope someone can help.

I'm scraping using BeautifulSoup 4 in a Python 3 environment. On the site that I'm scraping, I'm trying to get the specific values of text in the same span class. The span class says:

`<span class="TeamChip__teamName--1renR">MIL</span>
<span class="TeamChip__teamName--1renR">CIN</span>`

(Team names I'm trying to get).

When I use the find function, it scrapes both names into one string in the output csv, but I would like a solution where it separates them by using a delimiter of some sort, or into their cells (whichever). Right now it comes out as MILCIN, and I would like it to be something like MIL,CIN.

This is my Python code, with a few of the solutions I've tried commented out:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

with open('BoxScoreURLS.csv', newline='') as f_urls, open('output.csv', 'w', `newline='') as f_output:`
csv_urls = csv.reader(f_urls)
csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
csv_output.writerow(['Teams', 'Box Score'])

for line in csv_urls:
    r = requests.get(line[0]).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
    teams = soup.find("span", {"class":"TeamChip__teamName--1renR"})
    print('Teams :', teams.text)
    #person = {}

    #for span in soup.findAll('span', {'class': '.TeamChip__teamName--1renR'}):
    #   person[span.find('p').attrs['class'][0]] = span.text.strip()

    #print(person)

    print([item.get_text(strip=True) for item in soup.findAll("span.TeamChip__teamName--1renR")])
    #teams = soup.find("div", {"class":"TeamChip__teamName"}).
    #print('Teams :', teams.text)


    csv_output.writerow([teams.text])
```

The output writes to the csv fine, but it writes both values in one string (MILCIN), but I would like it to be (MIL,CIN) so that I can clean up the data easier aferward. This method will be applied to scores as well, so I can't just accept an excel formula to split the data.

Thanks a lot! Let me know if I can answer any more questions.

Comment: Your code example is missing what exactly was assigned to the teams variable but it looks to me like what is in the print statement might be what should be in the write row parameters.

Comment: I belive that this might be your answer
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993854/is-there-innertext-equivalent-in-beautifulsoup-python)

Comment: Thanks soundstripe. I tried putting what was in the print command into the writerow and it didn't return anything to the output? And you're right, I was having issues with pasting my code. This is the missing bit. I will try to add it to my original post.

        teams = soup.find("span", {"class":"TeamChip__teamName--1renR"})
        print('Teams :', teams.text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used requests in this example. I've tested the code here and it works. The only thing i didn't test would be the outputting to a csv file. So if it still doesn't work I would assume it would be the way it is outputted.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("http://your-site.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.findAll('span', {'class' :'TeamChip__teamName--1renR'})
for r in range(len(results)):
    csv_output.writerow([results[r].text])
```

Comment: Yep this worked. Had to re-add the import csv at the top and I'll change the page variable so that it'll from my csv that has a list of urls, but the output works. It puts both team names into their own rows. Thanks so much!

Comment: Since this answer worked can you please mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yep this worked. Had to re-add the import csv at the top and I'll change the page variable so that it'll from my csv that has a list of urls, but the output works. It puts both team names into their own rows. Thanks so much!