# How to extract text from “data-at”?

Tags: python, html

I am trying to **scrape** the website of Sephora but I just cannot get the information I want, I am trying to extract the name of each perfume and I have tried 2 ways, to use "brand=soup.find(.....)[...]" and took it out of the loop, it then returned "sku_item_brand" which is not the thing I want, and the second way is the code below but I don't know why it is not working in the loop.  The error I am getting is **'NoneType' object is not subscriptable** Somebody please help!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.sephora.com/shop/perfume')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'html.parser')
perfume_containers = soup.find_all('div', class_="css-12egk0t")
# List to store the scraped data in
brands = []
for container in perfume_containers:
# The brand
  brand = container.find('span', class_='css-ktoumz')['data-at']
  brands.append(brand)
```

[HTML Code that I tried to extract from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qRn5.png)

Comment: I never used BeatifulSoup but I think you're looking for `text`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993854/is-there-an-innertext-equivalent-in-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

brand.text will return the text value

```
for container in perfume_containers:
    brand = container.find('span', class_='css-ktoumz')
    try:
        brands.append(brand.text)
    except AttributeError:
        continue

print(brands)
```

Output

```
['CHANEL', 'Viktor&Rolf', 'CHANEL', 'Juliette Has a Gun', 'TOM FORD', 'CHANEL', 'Yves Saint Laurent', 'Versace', 'Yves Saint Laurent', 'Chloé', 'Sephora Favorites', 'Valentino']
```

Comment: Thank you Lambo!  I noticed you added a try-except in the code, is that mean some of the perfume's name will not be able to be extracted which will cause the error?  So by adding this statement, it will keep the program continue?

Comment: In some cases the container does not contain the 'css-ktoumz' class, therefore the brand variable becomes a Nonetype. The try catch will then exclude these occurrences.

Comment: See edit also, the except should not be an open except but rather a AttributeError to catch the specific occurrence of this error

Comment: Thank you Lambo!