# Extracting a specific value of an <a href> tag

Tags: python, web-scraping

I need to scrape just the number off a website that is located in this tag. By the way I'm using Python and BeautifulSoup

```
<p class="cell-link">
  <a href="/#/miner-list/offline-list">17</a>
</p>
```

I have looked online for the solution but due to the fact that this website automatically updates every 5 minutes I cant seem to find a way to get this number. Any advice will be very helpful.

Comment: Is the only thing that changes in this snippet the number?
If yes then simply read the line and replace ```<a href="/#/miner-list/offline-list">``` and ```</a>``` with nothing and you´re good. Else you´ll probably need some regex replace

Comment: Yes, the only thing that changes is the number in the snippet, but I'm not for sure exactly what you are meaning by replacing with nothing?

Comment: Have a look at this answer, it might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8994150/4603295
And with this solution, you will not need regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex capture groups to get that number.  Use regex101.com to test your regex.

```
html = '<a href="/#/miner-list/offline-list">17</a>'

miner_num = re.sub('<a href=\"/#/miner-list/offline-list\">(.*)</a>', r'\1', html)
print(miner_num)
# 17
```

Comment: OK thank you, but this number changes about every 5 minutes on the website so if the value of html stays the same I don't think that if will be of much help because it would show the same number every time I run the script wouldn't it?

Comment: If you don't re-load the html, then yes, the html will become out of date.  But if you do re-load the html into your script, then the script will analyze the new html and get the new number.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using BeautifulSoup, use selector to find the value.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
text = '<p class="cell-link">\n  <a href="/#/miner-list/offline-list">17</a>\n</p>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
value = soup.select_one(".cell-link a").text
print(value) # 17
```

Selector `".cell-link a"` finds a `<a>` element whose parent has `class="cell-link"`.

Comment: I should have mentioned my overall goal of this project. This number will change every so often, so I am needing to run a script that is going to scrape this site every 5 minutes and if the number goes up from the previous scraping, it is going to send the employess that are on shift a text message through email(that part I can do). So if the the text is '<p class="cell-link">\n  <a href="/#/miner-list/offline-list">17</a>\n</p>' every time it wont do any good. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: So you will scrape the site, run the above code to extract value, then take action on that value every 5 minutes. If you want to track value changes, save that value to DB or just store it with a variable, depending on how you write your program.